# unable to link css with html...everything is fine but still no change

Tags: html, css

Below is the css file and i saved it in the name of mycss.css.and i have saved it in the exact folder where my html file is.but the external css is not working

Below is the html file where i included a link to my css.

```css
table,th,td
{
border:3px solid blue;
padding:10px;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPEe html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="css/text" href="mycss.css"></link>
   
 </head>
 
 <body>
  
  <table>  
  <tr><th colspan=2>Name</th><th>Marks</th></tr>  
  <tr><td>Sonoo</td><td>Jaiswal</td><td>60</td></tr>  
  <tr><td>James</td><td>William</td><td>80</td></tr>  
  <tr><td>Swati</td><td>Sironi</td><td>82</td></tr>  
  <tr><td>Chetna</td><td>Singh</td><td>72</td></tr>  
  </table> 
  
   
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try changing `<!DOCTYPEe html>` to `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `type="css/text"` to `type="text/css"`.

Comment: after changing  the !DOCTYPE try to check the path your stylesheet or try to clear cache of your browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few potential issues that you should fix regardless:

- The doctype declaration should be `<!DOCTYPE html>`
- The `type` attribute should actually be `text/css` not `css/text`
- If your filepaths are correct, try just hard refreshing the page with ctrl + shift + r

Answer (score 2):

The value "text/css" indicates that the content is CSS.

So you can't write css/text as it is not understand by the browsers

Secondly in HTML, the DOCTYPE is case insensitive. The following DOCTYPEs are all valid:

```
<!doctype html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!DoCtYpE hTmL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the attribute type to `type="text/css"`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your file is saved as mycss.css.css (that is doubling of file extension when you save file as .css but the save window also applies an additional .css extension), it could be a potential problem that your css file is not being recognized by the system due to doubling of .css extension.